# stream error in the http/2 framing layer in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

We are getting below error for wordpress site hosted in linux server

```
stream error in the http/2 framing layer
```

Due to this error, site is getting down frequently.
We couldn't track any specified error log also. so not sure about exact reason.

Note: We have 2 sites hosted in same server. But both configured with http2 protocol. But we are facing this issue in one site not in another. So is this specific to site configuration ? While comparing both configuration there is no major difference.

While debugging further, we are getting below issue details from CURL command

```
http2 error: Invalid HTTP header field was received: frame type: 1, stream: 1, name: [upgrade], value: [h2,h2c]
```

What we need to do to resolve this ?

Thanks in advance.